# How to toggle content of <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got this nice little function to toggle the content of a table. The content is stored in a `<div>` with the class "hiddenDiv". There is a `<span>` with the class "toggle" containing a link that when clicked opens the "hiddenDiv". I want to apply the whole script to the entire `<tr>`, so that when you click anywhere inside the `<tr>` it shows the "hiddenDiv". However, when I just change the class of the `<tr>` to "toggle" and delete the `<span>` class nothing happens.. Any help is appreciated!

```
$(".toggle").click(function () { 
  if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
    $(".hiddenDiv").hide();
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast"); 
  } else { 
    $(this).next().hide(); 
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
     <table width="96%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4">
      <tr class="toggle" id="messageRow">
        <td width="4%" valign="top">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="cb" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td width="20%" valign="top"><div class="message_name"><a href="../../pages/profile_page/profile_page.php?id=<?php echo $Sid; ?>"><?php echo $Fname.' '. $Lname ;?></a></div></td>
        <td width="58%" valign="top">
          <span style="padding:3px;">
          <a class="<?php echo $textWeight; ?>" id="subj_line_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="markAsRead(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo stripslashes($row['subject']); ?></a>
          </span>
          <div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDivId"> <br />
            <?php echo stripslashes(wordwrap(nl2br($row['message']), 54, "\n", true)); ?>
            <br /><br /><a href="javascript:toggleReplyBox('<?php echo stripslashes($row['subject']); ?>','<?php echo $my_uname; ?>','<?php echo $my_id; ?>','<?php echo $Sname; ?>','<?php echo $fr_id; ?>','<?php echo $thisRandNum; ?>')">Reply</a><br />
          </div>

       </td>
        <td width="18%" valign="top"><span style="font-size:10px;"><?php echo $date; ?></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: JavaScript works on HTML, which we can't see anywhere in this question. What does it look like?

Comment: Could you please show your HTML? The problem is that you're saying `$(this).next()` and the hidden div isn't the next element once you've put the click handler on the whole row. Is there one hidden div per row? Why are you using both `$(".hiddenDiv")` and `$(this).next()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hidden div you are talking about is in a td in the tr with the ".toggle" class then the following should work:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () { 
  var $hiddenDiv = $(this).find(".hiddenDiv");
  if ($hiddenDiv.is(":hidden")) {
    $hiddenDiv.slideDown("fast"); 
  } else { 
    $hiddenDiv.slideUp("fast"); 
  }
});
```

But you can simplify it as follows:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () { 
  $(this).find(".hiddenDiv").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

See the [`slideToggle()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

EDIT: Just saw your updated question with the html. If your element has an id then it is more efficient to select by id rather than class, i.e., `$("#hiddenDivId")` rather than `$(".hiddenDiv")`. Same for `$("#messageRow")` rather than `$(".toggle")`.

Also, you shouldn't use tables for non-tabular data.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The only thing I have to change is to close the opened div when another one is clicked! Thanks so much!

Comment: If you've got multiple rows each with their own div then yes, put `$(".hiddenDiv").hide()` as the first line inside the if case like you originally had. If you do have one per row you shouldn't be giving them all the same id.